# Profile URL with URL Router

Tags: php, url, get, url-routing

Currently, I'm on a small website.
After the user has logged in, he is redirected to his profile page.
until now i have routed the urls with the following code:

```
public function route($uri)
{

        $path = $uri;


        switch ($path) {
            case '/':
                return new FrontPageController;
            case '/login':
                return new LoginFormPageController;
            case '/action/login':
                return new LoginController;
            case '/register':
                return new RegisterFormPageController;
            case '/action/register':
                return new RegisterController;
            case '/Profile/' . :
                return new ProfilePageController;
            case '/logout':
                return new LogoutController();
            default:
                echo 'error';
        }
    }
```

But how do i do it by the profile page? 
The Profile uri should be like this: http://example.com/Profile/USERNAME and should be accessible from anywhere. 
I tried to do it with

```
case '/Profile/' . $_SESSION['username']:
                return new ProfilePageController;
```

But then only the logged user can see his own page.
How recogniue my router, that after Profile/ has entered a username? 
and how could i head after the login to the profile page?
Could i route to Profile/ and add the username manually?

Btw: i use NGINX pls don't say something like modify .htaccess

Comment: currently your $route variable can read static paths only. you need a way to extract the path params, probably regex would do. then pass those param array in to new ProfilePageController constructor. you will have your path params in the controller

Comment: i never worked with regex before... Is there another solution... :/ haha..

Answer (score 0):

You can change your case '/Profile/' block to something like this:

```
// check if route matches a pattern. preg_match return true if any matches found
case preg_match('/\/Profile\/([a-z0-9]+)/', $path, $matches): 

        // we remove the first element
        $params = array_shift($matches); 

        // pass params to construct
        return new ProfilePageController($params);
```

now back in your controller

```
class ProfilePageController   
{
    public function __construct($params)
    {
        $userid = $params[0];
    }

}
```